# AAsset_read vs fopen

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-ndk

I want to ask, what is recommended way to read from file, AAsset_read or standart fopen ? What are pros and cons of both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android app assets are not stored as standalone files. They're stored in APK, which is a ZIP archive. You cannot fopen() them.

Comment: But, if I have something on SD Card ?

Comment: Then fopen(). But you cannot Aasset_read() then, that's for compresset assets within the APK.